# GNU Parallel - Multiple arguments

Tags: python, shell, gnu-parallel, subsampling

Using GNU **parallel**, I am trying to run a sub-sampling script that inputs two files and outputs a specific subsampled file.  I am using this command:

```
parallel -j+0 --eta python sub_sample_.2.py ::: file1 file2 ::: file3 file4 ::: file5 file6
```

But there's no ETA on the command line, i.e.:

```
Computer:jobs running/jobs completed/%of started jobs/Average seconds to complete
ETA: 0s Left 8 AVG:0.00s local:8/0/1005/0.0
```

Also only the *first four* files are processed, but not the *last two*: `file5` and `file6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parallel -j+0 --eta python sub_sample_.2.py ::: file1 file2 ::: file3 file4 ::: file5 file6
```

2*2*2 = 8 jobs in total.

```
Computer:jobs running/jobs completed/%of started jobs/Average seconds to complete
ETA: 0s Left 8 AVG:0.00s local:8/0/1005/0.0
```

The ETA is computed on the runtime of jobs that finished. Here no jobs have finished yet, so there is no ETA. You can also see all 8 jobs are running on your local system, so you likely have 8 or more cores.

> Also only the *first four* files are processed, but not the *last two*: `file5` and `file6`.

Written this way I suspect you might not be aware of what multiple ::: do.  Run --dryrun and see if that is what you expect will be run.

My guess is that what you really want to run is (requires version 20160422 or later):

```
parallel --eta python sub_sample_.2.py ::: file1 file3 file5 :::+ file2 file4 file6
```

Or:

```
parallel --xapply --eta python sub_sample_.2.py ::: file1 file3 file5 ::: file2 file4 file6
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware that jobs had to finish in order to give an ETA. Just to be clear using :::+ is the same as using --xapply?

Comment: @Labrat The :::+ is a more advanced --xapply, but in this situation they do the same.

Comment: If I am using a command that takes an output and input argument such as:
samtools sort -n <output> <input>
How would I go about this in parallel?

Comment: parallel samtools sort -n {}.out {} ::: input*files

Comment: One last thing. When trying to run: parallel --eta htseq-count -m intersection-nonempty -i Name -s reverse -f bam {} <reference> >{}_htseq_Counts.txt 2>{}_OUTPUT_WARNINGS_.txt ::: *.bam it is writing the eta to "{}_OUTPUT_WARNINGS_.txt" and all the counts to "{}_htseq_Counts.txt" instead of seperate files. any help with this?

Comment: Try this: parallel --eta htseq-count -m intersection-nonempty -i Name -s reverse -f bam {} <reference> '>{}_htseq_Counts.txt 2>{}_OUTPUT_WARNINGS_.txt' ::: *.bam